# Is it a shortcut to making all double letters equal to the same single word using regex string replacement in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

So essentially, what I'm asking is if there is a way to replace ALL double letters (aa, bb,cc, dd, etc..) in a sentence by the SAME single word like "science" without having to make a dictionary with all the double letters and having to replace them. Is there a one line code using regular expressions that can achieve this in Python?

If not, I guess I'll have another 26 lines of code to do this lol.

Comment: You should know how *not to oversimplify* your problem when asking. Otherwise, the solution will be fitting to the scenario that you put up, but is not usable in your actual settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-liner, as requested:

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1', 'science', inputString)
```

If you want `AA` to be replaced, but not `aA`:

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\1', 'science', inputString)
```

If you want `AA` and `aA` to be replaced, specify case-insensitive flag `re.I`:

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1', 'science', inputString, flags = re.I)
```

Note that case-insensitive flag will cause the back-reference to do case-insensitive comparison also.

**Explanation**

I suggest that you read up on the documentation and get the hang of the very basic of regex, in particular character class `[]` before reading this explanation.

`(...)`, where the first character after `(` is not `?` means a *capturing group*. Well, `(?P<name>..)` is an exception to this rule, it is also a *capturing group*, but you can give a name to it, so it is called *named capturing group*. Capturing group will take note of portion of text that is matched by the pattern inside, so that you can refer to them later (in the regex or in replacement string).

Backreference `\number`, where `number` is a positive number, is how you check whether the current text is the same as the text matched by capturing group. (For named capturing group, you would use `(?P=name)`, same functionality but different syntax).

Take `([a-z])\1` as an example. It captures an English alphabet `[a-z]` (note the `()` surround it). Right after that, `\1` will checks that the next character (or sequence of characters, in general cases) is the same as the character matched by capturing group `([a-z])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nhahtdh. So \1 is an indicator for repeating letters?

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot. It's starting to make a lot of sense now :D

Comment: Hey, I was thinking as a side thought, if I wanted to include some double letters but not all.... How would I write the exclusions in regex? For example all double letters except aa or oo... Those would just remain the same as they are. How would I signify that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Euridice01: If you mean, all English alphabet, except a-o, then `[b-np-z]`, or you can just list out all of them (by string concatenation in a loop or high-order functions) `[bcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz]`. There is another simpler way but **NOT recommended** `[^ao]`, but it means including everything (Unicode character, control characters, etc.) except `a` and `o`.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. What if I wanted something like "science" followed by the letter that was repeated? so, like bb = scienceb .

Comment: @Euridice01: Replacement string `r'science\1'`

Comment: Oh one more thing, I'm noticing if I type something like this: "re.sub(r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1', 'science', text, flags = re.I), where I have the word "bbbiirdd" and I want to replace bbb and dd with the string "science", it translates takes the word science and doesn't really replace it. It just uses the string replacement for science that I made lol. I wonder why? Sorry for all the questions but thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Euridice01: You *initially* ask for **double letter**, but now it becomes a **repeated sequence of letters**. Next time, please make a new question if you are going to change your requirement so much. As for how, use this regex `r'([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1+'` (`+` means repeats once or more).

Comment: oh no, that's not what I meant. I'll ask another question. Sorry for the trouble but thank you so much for all your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a dictionary at all, just match doubled letters:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<letter>[a-z])(?P=letter)', 'science', 'some aa doubled dd letters')
'some science doubled science lescienceers'
```

The `(?P<name>..)` group is referred to by the `(?P=letter)` match so only doubled letters are matched. It is a slightly more verbose way of using `r'([a-z])\1'` that is more self-documenting.